# jQuery Datatables transform html table to ajax for using processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

The source for my datatables is a a html table. In the first row I add a hyperlink to another page.

It is all working fine but I want to show the user the `processing` text when the table is loading. As I understand this is only possible if I use AJAX.

Is there a simple way to convert the existing html table into a AJAX source? The original table has more than 30 columns which is filled by an oracle db.

```
<table id='liste' class='display' cellspacing='0' style='width:100%'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th align='center'>Info</th>
<th align='center'>Number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align='center'><a href='Eingabe.aspx?ID=0'><img src='images/edit.svg' title='bearbeiten'></a></td>
<td align='center'>Info1</td>
<td align='center'>20000</td>
...and many more...
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Info</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#liste').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
select: true,
fixedHeader: {
header: true,
footer: true},
order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
paging: false,
processing: true,
columnDefs: [{ targets: 3, data: 'Number', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 0, '', ' €') },
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: DataTables.net supports ajax calls. https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: @VDWWD Yeah I know, bur i have a html table as source. If I use `ajax: '/api/myData',` I get an error for the ajax source

Comment: If you have MVC or Core you can return an Action that only returns a html table. Call that Action with Ajax, append it to the HTML and re-init DataTables.net

Comment: @VDWWD Sry, this is my first time with Ajax. Can you please explain a little bit more? I consider if it would be possible to save the html table as json file and call the file with Ajax. But does this work with my hyperlink? The table is very complex so it would take much time try this

Comment: How does your table get generated initially, before you try to convert it to datatables?  Which bit takes the most time - loading the page with the table already in it, or converting to datatables?

Comment: You could do a simple `<div id="loading">Processing...</div><table style='display:none;'...` then when datatables complete converting hide the processing and fadein the table.

Comment: This might help? https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22619/how-do-i-show-a-loading-message-when-i-load-the-table-from-a-new-ajax-call

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks that is a good idea. I will give it a try

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks I will try it